# Make view matrix from non-standard axis convention?

Tags: matrix, coordinate-transformation

My coordinate system is:

x forward

y left

z up

How do I make a view matrix that works in that space?

I tried

forw_x, left_x, up_x, x

forw_y, left_y, up_y, y

forw_z, left_z, up_z, z

0, 0, 0, 1

to no avail..

Comment: Assuming that you are using column vectors, the above matrix is the **inverse** of the correct view matrix. There are more efficient (and numerically stable) ways to construct the view matrix than to directly perform an inversion though...

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks. Must admit I have no clue which inversion technique too use or how to find those other ways of constructing it..

Comment: [This page](https://www.3dgep.com/understanding-the-view-matrix/) might be of help to you (beware of any differences in the coordinate convention); if you are still not sure I can post an answer.